# Triggering an event when YouTube video reaches certain timestamp?

Tags: youtube-javascript-api

The API documentation does not contain an obvious way to trigger a javascript event when a YouTube video reaches a certain time stamp. Do you know any workaround?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a timer which check at second whether video has reached certain timestamp.
To restrict unnecessary function calls, start time only when it reaches your set time

```
var timeout = setTimeout(function(){
  var interval = setInterval(function(){
    if(player.getCurrentTime() === <you_set_time>){
        clearInterval(interval);
        // Your logic
    }

  },1000);
},<your_set_time_in_millisecs>);
```

Comment: The polling approach turned out to be exactly what I needed.

Comment: Is there some functionality for android?

Answer (score 2):

To avoid unnecessary processing, you can wait for player to enter PLAYING state, then, put a setTimeout function with the remaining time until time stamp.

In case of buffering, anytime the player resumes PLAYING states, call the same function, which clears the previous setTimeout and sets the new one (if remaining time positive)

Here is the jsfiddle POC : http://jsfiddle.net/V6rgy/